# Can't deply echo bot to azure bot services

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service

I'm creating my first chat bot in azure + c# (in general I'm novice in azure too). I've downloaded BotFramework v4 SDK Templatests for VS22 and use a simple echo bot. It works localy with Bot Framework emulator (with this endpoint http://localhost:3978/api/messages).

[image]

Now I want to install this bot on azure.
I used these steps:

1. In VS with "Publish" wizard I've create an azure web app.
2. When I run this app from azure (https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/) I see a default web page with "Your bot is ready!" and steps that suggest using emulator or visit "Azure Bot Service" to register your bot. I need the second one but can't really open the provided link. It goes to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/bot-services which loose authentication, so it simply says you can use "Azure Bot Service". LogIn doesn't really help since it redirects just on the root azure portal page.
3. However, I think I know how the above issue can be solved. I've simply created a new "Azure Bot (Microsoft)" in `Bot services` manually.

[image]

4. Now, I want to connect my echo bot logic in the deployed web application with the created azure bot from services. As far as I can understand, for this I should provide "https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/api/messages" to the `Messaging endpoint` uri and then I should be able to check my bot in `Test in Web Chat` window. But I see nothing there, No hello message, no output, no errors. I only see that my test request message was sent.

[image]

I've described pretty all steps I have done, what could I miss? I assume my application is not visisble for chat bot for some reason, how can I troubleshot it? Any other suggestions are welcome.

**UPDATE**: Initially all 4 fields configuration in `appsettings.json` in my c# application were missed.
Now they have the following values:

1. `MicrosoftAppType` - still nothing. I don't know yet which value should be here.
2. `MicrosoftAppTenantId` - I found this value in `Azure Active Directory` -> `App registrations` -> `My Azure Bot name` -> `Overview` -> Directory (tenant) ID
3. `MicrosoftAppId` - I took this value from `My azure bot service` page -> `Configuration` -> `Microsoft App ID (Manage Password)`
4. `MicrosoftAppPassword` - This value is taken from `My azure bot service` page -> `Configuration` -> Clicking on `Microsoft App ID (Manage Password)` link -> `New Client secret` -> `Value`.

I'm not 100% confident that all these values are taken from the right place and what value should be in `MicrosoftAppType`

**UPDATE2**:
I've found description for `appsettings.json` fields [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/provision-and-publish-a-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned%2Ccsharp) in section `Bot identity information`. I assume I need to use `UserAssignedMSI` `MicrosoftAppType`, so the values are slightly modified:

```
"MicrosoftAppType": "UserAssignedMSI",
"MicrosoftAppId": "%Microsoft_App_ID_(Manage_Password)_from_bot_service_configuration%",
"MicrosoftAppPassword": "",
"MicrosoftAppTenantId": "%tenantId%"
```

still gives the same result without errors or any output.

Comment: You can read the documentation on how to deploy a bot here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/provision-and-publish-a-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned%2Ccsharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, my bot application is actually `MultiTenant` app, as soon as I've changed it, it became working. I have a question whether I can have it configured as singletenant, but it's probably a diff question. Resolved.